# What is tension in cabel of elevator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, acceleration

A block of mass $m$ is kept on the floor of an elevator of mass $M$ and the system is accelerating upward with acceleration $a$. The acceleration due to gravity is $g$.
$F_n$ is Normal force on Block.
where
$$F_n = (a+g)m$$

Now, is
$$T=(M+m)g +(M+m)a \tag{i}$$
or
(as from some solution)
"taking Total upward forces"
$$T+F_n =(M+m)g +(M+m)a \tag{ii}$$

In some books I found equation (ii) but how can it be so?
I think $F_n$ is already included in Tension.
further calculating equation (ii) gives 
$$T=(a+g)M$$
It seems like Tension is reduced when anything is added.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Whoever said "taking the total upward force  $T + F_n$" is wrong. The tension of the cable and the *upward* normal force act on different objects, so it makes no sense to add them together.

You have two choices in how to think about this problem that lead to the same solution:

1. Consider the elevator and block as a single object of mass $M+m$. There are two forces: the cable tension and gravity. This works as long as the elevator and block move together.
2. Consider the motion of the elevator alone. There are three forces on it: the cable tension, gravity, and the force of the block on the floor. You find the force of the block on the floor by figuring out what force from the floor would cause the block to accelerate upwards, then apply Newton's third law to get the force on the floor.

I recommend doing both so you can check your answers and get practice working with multiple interacting objects.